# Use onError twice

Tags: javascript, onerror

Is there a way to use onError twice if the first onError doesn't exist

```
<img class="media-object img-responsive" src="/img/product/{{ product_type_slug }}/thumb/{{ image_thumb }}" alt="{{ name }}"
onError="
this.onerror=null;
this.src='/img/product/swatch/{{ image }}';">
```

Looking for an onError for the onError to show:

```
src='/img/product/{{ product_type_slug }}/old/{{ image_thumb }}'
```

so if the original image doesnt exist show swatch url, if that doesnt exist show old.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a javascript function to deal with this scenario

```js
function loadAlternative(element, list) {
  var image = new Image();

  image.onload = function() {
    element.src = this.src;
  }

  image.onerror = function() {
    if (list.length) {
      loadAlternative(element, list);
    }
  }

  //  pick off the first url in the list
  image.src = list.shift();
}
```

```html
<img src="nope.jpg" 
     data-alternative="njet.jpg,neither.jpg,http://lorempixel.com/400/200/technics/1/" 
     onerror="loadAlternative(this, this.getAttribute('data-alternative').split(/,/))">
```

What this does:

- you set an error handler to load an alternative image
- you provide alternatives as a comma-separated list in an `data-alternative` attribute
- if the `onerror` is triggered, the `loadAlternative` function is called with both the element (`img`) and the `data-alternative` list as array
- for as long as the image cannot be loaded and there is another one in the list, it will repeat the process
- once an image is loaded, it will be set as `src` on the `element`

---

If you need some default image to be used should all alternatives fail, you could modify the `image.onerror` function to deal with an empty list like this:

```
  image.onerror = function() {
    if (list.length) {
      loadAlternative(element, list);
    }
    else {
      element.src = '/every/other/option/has/failed.jpg';
    }
  }
```

---

Please note that you could (on the web this means: *you will*) end up with a lot of attempts to load images, which may be prevented by having the server check for the existence of images.

Comment: Just doesn't seem to work with my dynamic src's :/ your answer is right though for static src's, this still just displays /img/product/{{ product_type_slug }}/thumb/{{ image_thumb }} which is missing for some products and just showing a broken image

Comment: to the browser there is no difference between static and dynamic, it's just an image source. did you put the alternative in the `data-alternative` attribute? e.g. `data-alternative="/img/product/swatch/{{ image }}"`?

Comment: Yeah I copied yours and replaced your src's to mine, i'll keep trying